# Onload event is not firing after passing Html string through window.open in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a scenario, I am receiving Html comtent as a string from java service and I am trying to render this through Angular using window.open method. Html elements are data is diplaying, but while loading window javascript onload event is not triggering.

Html string receiving from java:

```
<html><h1>Workflow Detailed Report modified</h1><head><script type=text/javascript>function loadReport() {alert('Load Report'); window.open("http://google.com","_self")}</script></head><body onload="loadReport()"></body></html>
```

In Angular function using below code to open new window with above string.

```
const win = window.open('', '_blank', 'left=50,top=50,width=1334,height=700');
win.document.write(htmlData);
```

Is there any better way to handle this scenario in Angular 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `document.write()`, you have to call [`document.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/close) afterwards to finalize the document, otherwise the `load` event will not be fired.

```js
const win = window.open('', '_blank', 'left=50,top=50,width=1334,height=700');
win.document.write(htmlData);
win.document.close();
```

Comment: you are just awesome, my issue is resolved. I did a kind of phd on this issue. Thank you.